# Add/Remove from cart button for Shopify

Tags: html

So myself and a friend have just got into website building and we have our first customer, he basically wants us to replicate www.rayburntrading.com, which is fine, we can do that... But we're struggling with adding the option to add/remove that is shown under the products.

I don't suppose anyone could help by providing the HTML/Liquid Code for me?

Also, any links to places to learn HTML/Liquid Code would be appreicated.

Thanks (y)

//FFG

Comment: What is your usual rate for subcontractors?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the Shopify AJAX cart api
Here are the links you are looking for

https://github.com/carolineschnapp/ajaxify-cart

https://help.shopify.com/themes/development/getting-started/using-ajax-api

You will need to use AJAX to post to the shop cart api when a button under the product is clicked. Similarly you can remove a product by posting a remove request using the AJAX api.

Please mark this as the answer if it was helpful to you. Happy coding.
It is also a good idea to post on the Shopify forums.